# Restart the first function after finished the second

Tags: javascript, function

I have 2 functions in my script:

```
function ShowAltTag(){
    var CurrentImage = $("#ShowImage img").attr("src");
    if( $.browser.msie ) {
        IECurrentImage (CurrentImage);
    }       
    if ($(".ImageRoller img[src='" +CurrentImage+ "']").attr("alt")){
        var alt = $(".ImageRoller img[src='" +CurrentImage+ "']").attr("alt");
        $("#ShowImage").append("<div class='alt'><span>" +alt+ "</span></div>");
        $("#ShowImage div.alt").fadeIn("fast");             
    }                               
}

function IECurrentImage (CurrentImage)
{   
    var loc = document.location.href;
    CurrentImage = CurrentImage.replace(/\ /g, "%20");
    CurrentImage = loc.substring( 0, loc.lastIndexOf( '/' ) ) +'/'+ CurrentImage;   
}
```

If the browser is IE it starts the function IECurrentImage , but after that the script should make the rest of ShowAltTag with the new value of Current Image.

Is that even possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: after clicking ok for the alert of "finishedB", you don't see the "finishedA" alert? Normally you should, unless you do something special in FunctionB() which prevents it from returning properly

Comment: are you sure `InfoVar == 100` ?

Comment: i've inserted now the whole code in which I have the problem, mabey the error is in there

Comment: try to add some more alerts in your code, in every if, to see whether the code really gets executed

Comment: ah, now I have the problem, in the function IECurrentImage the var CurrentImage gets modified. But after that I must work with the new var CurrentImage in the first function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `return` keyword to return the new value, and assign the variable to the `CurrentImage` variable in the first function.

```
function IECurrentImage (CurrentImage)
{   
    var loc = document.location.href;
    CurrentImage = CurrentImage.replace(/\ /g, "%20");
    return loc.substring( 0, loc.lastIndexOf( '/' ) ) + '/' + CurrentImage;   
}

function ShowAltTag()
{
    var CurrentImage = $("#ShowImage img").attr("src");
    if ( $.browser.msie ) {
        CurrentImage = IECurrentImage(CurrentImage);
    } 

    // Etc.
}
```

Even though the variables in both functions have identical names, they are actually different variables, as each function has their own variable scope.

Alternatively, you can remove the existing `var CurrentImage` statements and put it outside and in front of both of these functions. This would make it a global variable. You shouldn't use global variables unless it's actually necessary though.

You might want to read [this article about local and global variables](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tutorials/javascript/global_local_variables_scope_javascript.php3) in JavaScript.

Comment: that's it :) 
thank's to all for the help, and I apologize for the chaos I've made^^